# Logwatch is not sending mail to my email address on CentOS

Tags: postfix, logwatch

I assume logwatch is using postfix because this is what I see in the log files..

```
2014-11-03T15:01:35.509850+11:00 workshop2 postfix/smtpd[7048]: disconnect from ami[127.0.0.1]
2014-11-03T15:01:42.246241+11:00 workshop2 postfix/smtp[7052]: 7A5A5408F0: to=<XXX.XXX@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.20.27]:25, delay=6.8, delays=0.01/0.02/0.84/5.9, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1414987301 lr3si14396502pab.140 - gsmtp)
2014-11-03T15:01:42.246503+11:00 workshop2 postfix/qmgr[5976]: 7A5A5408F0: removed
```

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1 ami ami.workshop2
192.168.56.102 khadija.ahlanwsahlan.com khadija
127.0.0.1   localhost hol localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost hol localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

**/etc/postfix/main.cf**

```
#
myorigin = khadija.ahlanwsahlan.com
myorigin = ahlanwsahlan.com
```

- I can telnet to the mail server at `gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com` on `port 25`
- I have changed `inet_protocols = all` to `inet_protocols = ipv4` in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`

One thing which I am not sure about is when mail is being sent from my local Linux server, what will the sending email address be?
Note that ahlanwsahlan.com is not a real domain.

```
mail -s "test subject" XXX.XXX@gmail.com < message.txt
sendmail XXX.XXX@gmail.com < ~/message.txt
```

The above commands do not send any mail either.

Many thanks.

Comment: Your logs show that the mail is accepted by `gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.20.27]:25`, check in your gmail `Spam` folder.

Comment: It worked! Didn't even think of looking there. The sending address looks funny though because it's a private IP - 192.168.56.102@workshop2
Cheers.